# Remove Google Account to unlock get adb permission denied

Tags: adb, restore

I forgot my PIN and I dont know which Google Account I used and now I try to remove the question for my Google account data. So I try it with [this How-To](https://www.droidwiki.de/wiki/Muster_vergessen) and when I try to run `sqlite3 settings.db` after running adb shell I got an "Permissions denied". What can I do in this case?

Technical Informations: I have a Samsung S5570 mini with I think an Android 4